# Should I use ternary relationship for these entities

Tags: entity-relationship

I have these entities in ER model from my project:

- Student
- Professor
- Subject

Should I connect them with ternary relationship, or each one with binary relationships? I used ternary relationship. Maybe i don't have the best possible name for the relationship, but it involves grading.

[image]

And also if i should use ternary relationship which Ids from connected tables should i use as primary key for the table which will represent relationship in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your diagram, it seems that each `Student`/`Subject` combination determines a `Professor`. Let's compare this with binary relationships:

A binary relationship between `Student` and `Subject` would allow you to record which `Students` are taking which `Subjects`, without specifying which `Professor`. Is that valid for your system, or is it necessary to capture the `Professor` for every `Student`/`Subject` combination?

A binary relationship between `Student` and `Professor` would record a `Professor` for each `Student`, or possibly a set of of `Professors` for each `Student`. Is this useful without knowing which subject each `Professor` teaches to the `Student`?

A binary relationship between `Subject` and `Professor` would record one or more `Professors` for each subject. That could be useful to capture what a `Professor` is able or qualified to teach, as opposed to what they're assigned or scheduled to teach.

I've worked on two school administration systems, and we captured `(Student PK, Subject PK)` (subjects taken by students) and `(Professor PK, Subject PK)` (subjects that can be taught be professors), but instead of a ternary relationship `(Student PK, Subject PK, Professor)`, we defined a subject group or section `Sections (SectionID PK, Subject, Professor)` and student section allocation `(Student PK, Subject PK, SectionID)`. Subject groups or sections provide a convenient place to attach further attributes, like Room number, timetabling arrangements, tuition language, etc.